# Extract iteratively data in subfolders within folder into googledrive

Tags: r, google-drive-api, export, readxl

In a general folder, I have this subset of subfolders which I would like to open iteratively to download datasets in .xlsx format

In the following major folder:

[image]

there are these subfolders that as you could see has a specific pattern name

[image]

and within each of them, there is a .xlsx dataset

[image]

named as similarly as the main subfolder where it is contained

I was wondering on extract them using some iterative function. Based on the code I have found through the forum I have found something that I have readapted as for loop, but with no results.

```
url = 'urlnamexxx'
for (folder in url) {
  temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
  download.file(url, temp)
  readxl::read_xlsx(temp)
}
```

Could you please give some suggestions?

Please in case something is not clear, just comment down below and let me the details I should provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you provided is intended to download a single Excel file from a given URL, save it as a temporary file, and then read it into R using the [`readxl::read_xlsx()` function](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html). This will not work for multiple URLs or for URLs that point to directories rather than files.

To extract data from Google Drive in a structured manner, you would need to use Google Drive's API, which provides a way to list and download files. For R, there are several packages that can facilitate this, such as [`googledrive`](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/).

That would involve:

1. Authenticate with Google Drive:

   ```r
   library(googledrive)
   drive_auth()
   ```
2. Identify the parent folder:

   ```r
   folder <- drive_get("~/path/to/your/parent/folder")
   ```
3. List all subfolders:

   ```r
   subfolders <- drive_ls(path = folder)
   ```
4. Loop over the subfolders, identifying and downloading the `.xlsx` files:

   ```r
   for (i in 1:nrow(subfolders)) {
       subfolder <- subfolders[i,]
       files <- drive_ls(path = subfolder)
       xlsx_files <- files[grepl("\\.xlsx$", files$name),]
       for (j in 1:nrow(xlsx_files)) {
           file <- xlsx_files[j,]
           drive_download(file, path = "~/path/to/save/files", overwrite = TRUE)
       }
   }
   ```

This script authenticates with Google Drive, locates the parent folder, lists its subfolders, and then iterates over these subfolders to identify and download the `.xlsx` files they contain.

Do replace `"~/path/to/your/parent/folder"` and `"~/path/to/save/files"` with your actual paths.

That script assumes that you have already set up Google Drive API credentials and that the `googledrive` package has been installed (`install.packages("googledrive")`).
And make sure you have the necessary permissions to access the files and folders on Google Drive.

Comment: thank you so much. I have readapted the code and it works fine (meaning that I can run the download). However, I cannot see the folders downloaded in my desired folders. Can you guess how come?

Comment: my error. I have set the wrong working directory. Thank you. The code works great